# how do i implement user input in loop in the following code?

Tags: java

this is guess number programme using constructor but the issue which I am facing
is not able to express user input in loop.I tried to look for it but not good explanation.

```
import  java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
class guessnumber{


public int getRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
return (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)) + min);
}

public String userinput(int repeats,int rand){
String e;
e="that's it";
if(repeats<rand){
    String z="choose higher number";
    System.out.println(z);
}
else if (repeats>rand){
    String z="choose lower number";
    System.out.println(z);
}
return e;
}
public String iscorrect(){
String correct="correct number";
return correct;
}
}
public class guessthenumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
guessnumber gun = new guessnumber();
System.out.println("enter number ");
int number = sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("enter max and min number");
int min = sc.nextInt();
int max = sc.nextInt();
int o=gun.getRandomNumber(min,max);
System.out.println(o);
if (number < o || number > o) {
    System.out.println(gun.userinput(number, o));}

else if(number==o){
   String correct= gun.iscorrect();
    System.out.println(correct);

}
}
}
```

I want to user to keep entering data till correct number is hit

Comment: You need to make use of a `while` loop. See this section from the official Java tutorial: [The while and do-while Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). The short explanation is that you need to wrap all the code that needs to repeat inside the `while` loop. If you want to keep values between loops then declare them before/outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [while](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [break](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) statements

Comment: thx I got it it was such a noobie mistake.one more question how do print in methods when i use void it isn't allowing me to use print lt show"cant resolve print(void)"

Comment: sry, I don't understand what you're talking about. If you want to use `System.out.println()` , parentheses cannot nest methods that do not return a value (that is, a method whose return value is `void`)

Comment: Example: `void fun1(){....}` and `System.out.println( fun1() );` this is wrong; `string fun2(){retrun "Hello world"}` and `System.out.println( fun2() )` that's correct!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that behaves like you're describing, and how your code currently behaves:

- ask for a few numbers up front (minimum, maximum)
- determine a random "target" number for the user to guess
- ask the user to guess – if they're correct, show a message; if they're incorrect, ask for another guess
- repeat until their guess is correct

A few things I did:

- introduce a "getNumber()" helper that will make sure the numbers make sense – put some guardrails around what a user can enter to minimize unexpected results if user enters unexpected input
- use a "while" loop, go forever – `while (true)`
- if their guess matches the target, use `break` to stop the loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int minimum = getNumber(scanner, 0, "minimum");
    int maximum = getNumber(scanner, minimum + 1, "maximum");
    int target = (int) ((Math.random() * (maximum - minimum)) + minimum);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("enter a guess: ");
        int guess = scanner.nextInt();
        if (guess == target) {
            System.out.println("correct guess! the number was " + target);
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.print("nope, please try again.. ");
        }
    }
}

static int getNumber(Scanner scanner, int minimumAllowed, String numberType) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("enter " + numberType + " number: ");
        int minimum = scanner.nextInt();
        if (minimum >= minimumAllowed) {
            return minimum;
        } else {
            System.out.println("too small, must be at least " + minimumAllowed);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a sample run:

```
enter minimum number: 1
enter maximum number: -3
too small, must be at least 2
enter maximum number: 5
enter a guess: 1
nope, please try again.. enter a guess: 2
nope, please try again.. enter a guess: 3
nope, please try again.. enter a guess: 4
correct guess! the number was 4
```